# Autofocusing multi v single point at a party

Tags: autofocus, focus, night, indoor

## Context

I've shot at a party at night recently. I've used mainly multi point (continuous) tracking as it makes more sense, as random events may come and go.

## Question

My friend suggests that I should have used single point to increase the amount of images worth keeping. I don't do that but I do bracketing, and it improves my keeper count, as well as just taking multiple shots. If Single point AF preferred when you're shooting at such events or is it more of a personal choice?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What autofocus zone selection mode should I use for action/event shooting?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/23551/what-autofocus-zone-selection-mode-should-i-use-for-action-event-shooting) and also see [Why would I want to select an autofocus point?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12150/why-would-i-want-to-select-an-autofocus-point) and [What's the difference between cross-type autofocus points and regular ones?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9785/whats-the-difference-between-cross-type-autofocus-points-and-regular-ones)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single point or even manual focus, plus focus lock. The lock allows you to quickly focus with a half press of the shutter and then recompose to shoot. That way the focus is where you want it which may not be the centre of the frame.

Comment: Divorcing focus from the shutter button altogether and using the back button for focusing works even better, as it preserves the locked focus distance for multiple shots.

Answer (score -1):

Pictures look sharper when a camera is focusing at the middle focus point.  I'd say that you probably would slightly increase your chances of getting more images with a crisp focus if you switch to single point and keep that point in the middle.

Comment: Are you suggesting that using a focus point other than the center point results in less than optimal focus? As far as selecting multi-point vs single, it depends on the scenario and shooting conditions as well as technique and skills of the user, and a blanket statement that one is better than the other can't be said.

Comment: In low light the center point usually focuses more accurately and faster on most Canon EOS models as well as a lot of other brands, especially if a lens f/2.8 or wider is used. This is because it is usually a cross point compared to other focus points that are vertical only or horizontal only focus points, or even a double cross point (with one cross point oriented diagonally) with a wider baseline compared to single cross points or hor/vert only points at the other positions.

Comment: But do "pictures look sharper". No.